# Convert a 2d matrix to a 3d one hot matrix numpy

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization, one-hot-encoding

I have np matrix and I want to convert it to a 3d array with one hot encoding of the elements as third dimension. Is there a way to do with without looping over each row 
eg

```
a=[[1,3],
   [2,4]]
```

should be made into

```
b=[[1,0,0,0], [0,0,1,0],
   [0,1,0,0], [0,0,0,1]]
```

Answer (score 59, accepted):

### Approach #1

Here's a cheeky one-liner that abuses [`broadcasted`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) comparison -

```
(np.arange(a.max()) == a[...,None]-1).astype(int)
```

Sample run -

```
In [120]: a
Out[120]: 
array([[1, 7, 5, 3],
       [2, 4, 1, 4]])

In [121]: (np.arange(a.max()) == a[...,None]-1).astype(int)
Out[121]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

For `0-based` indexing, it would be -

```
In [122]: (np.arange(a.max()+1) == a[...,None]).astype(int)
Out[122]: 
array([[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

If the one-hot enconding is to cover for the range of values ranging from the minimum to the maximum values, then offset by the minimum value and then feed it to the proposed method for `0-based` indexing. This would be applicable for rest of the approaches discussed later on in this post as well.

Here's a sample run on the same -

```
In [223]: a
Out[223]: 
array([[ 6, 12, 10,  8],
       [ 7,  9,  6,  9]])

In [224]: a_off = a - a.min() # feed a_off to proposed approaches

In [225]: (np.arange(a_off.max()+1) == a_off[...,None]).astype(int)
Out[225]: 
array([[[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]]])
```

If you are okay with a boolean array with `True` for `1's` and False for `0's`, you can skip the `.astype(int)` conversion.

### Approach #2

We can also initialize a zeros arrays and index into the output with [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing). Thus, for `0-based` indexing, we would have -

```
def onehot_initialization(a):
    ncols = a.max()+1
    out = np.zeros(a.shape + (ncols,), dtype=int)
    out[all_idx(a, axis=2)] = 1
    return out
```

Helper func -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46103129/ @Divakar
def all_idx(idx, axis):
    grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, idx.shape))]
    grid.insert(axis, idx)
    return tuple(grid)
```

This should be especially more performant when dealing with larger range of values.

For `1-based` indexing, simply feed in `a-1` as the input.

### Approach #3 : Sparse matrix solution

Now, if you are looking for sparse array as output and AFAIK since scipy's inbuilt sparse matrices support only `2D` formats, you can get a sparse output  that is a reshaped version of the output shown earlier with the first two axes merging and the third axis being kept intact. The implementation for `0-based` indexing would look something like this -

```
from scipy.sparse import coo_matrix
def onehot_sparse(a):
    N = a.size
    L = a.max()+1
    data = np.ones(N,dtype=int)
    return coo_matrix((data,(np.arange(N),a.ravel())), shape=(N,L))
```

Again, for `1-based` indexing, simply feed in `a-1` as the input.

Sample run -

```
In [157]: a
Out[157]: 
array([[1, 7, 5, 3],
       [2, 4, 1, 4]])

In [158]: onehot_sparse(a).toarray()
Out[158]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])

In [159]: onehot_sparse(a-1).toarray()
Out[159]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]])
```

This would be much better than previous two approaches if you are okay with having sparse output.

**Runtime comparison for 0-based indexing**

Case #1 :

```
In [160]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100))

In [161]: %timeit (np.arange(a.max()+1) == a[...,None]).astype(int)
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.51 ms per loop

In [162]: %timeit onehot_initialization(a)
1000 loops, best of 3: 478 µs per loop

In [163]: %timeit onehot_sparse(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.5 µs per loop

In [164]: %timeit onehot_sparse(a).toarray()
1000 loops, best of 3: 530 µs per loop
```

Case #2 :

```
In [166]: a = np.random.randint(0,500,(100,100))

In [167]: %timeit (np.arange(a.max()+1) == a[...,None]).astype(int)
100 loops, best of 3: 8.51 ms per loop

In [168]: %timeit onehot_initialization(a)
100 loops, best of 3: 2.52 ms per loop

In [169]: %timeit onehot_sparse(a)
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.1 µs per loop

In [170]: %timeit onehot_sparse(a).toarray()
100 loops, best of 3: 2.67 ms per loop
```

### Squeezing out best performance

To squeeze out the best performance, we could modify approach #2 to use indexing on a `2D` shaped output array and also use `uint8` dtype for memory efficiency and that leading to much faster assignments, like so -

```
def onehot_initialization_v2(a):
    ncols = a.max()+1
    out = np.zeros( (a.size,ncols), dtype=np.uint8)
    out[np.arange(a.size),a.ravel()] = 1
    out.shape = a.shape + (ncols,)
    return out
```

Timings -

```
In [178]: a = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100))

In [179]: %timeit onehot_initialization(a)
     ...: %timeit onehot_initialization_v2(a)
     ...: 
1000 loops, best of 3: 474 µs per loop
10000 loops, best of 3: 128 µs per loop

In [180]: a = np.random.randint(0,500,(100,100))

In [181]: %timeit onehot_initialization(a)
     ...: %timeit onehot_initialization_v2(a)
     ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 2.38 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 213 µs per loop
```

Comment: I call this Numpythonic!

Comment: you probably don't actually want the `.astype(int)` here, since that incurs an unnecessary copy

Comment: @Eric Well, without it the output would be a boolean array and OP wants an int array it seems. Or am I missing something?

Comment: This is more a remark aimed at the OP, and how they probably want the boolean array in the first place. Viewing as an `np.int8` might elide the copy

Comment: Good point, yes boolean arrays would do the job too, I will keep that in mind, @Divakar is there any way to make this sparse in ints or booleans?

Comment: That's much more than cheeky !

Comment: I think this is truly an awesome trick, and I just wanted to share that you can  even make it work with arrays or an arbitrary number of dimensions with this slight modification to the magic line: `(np.arange(a.max()) == a[..., None]-1).astype(int)`

Comment: Just in case anyone needed onehot shape of [N, H, W] like I do, simply invert the shape of `out` in function `onehot_initialization_v2` like this:  `out = np.zeros( (ncols, a.size), dtype=np.uint8)` and `out[a.ravel(), np.arange(a.size)] = 1`, `out.shape = (ncols,) + a.shape`. Notice that `.reshape` on original function won't do.

Answer (score 4):

If you are trying to create one-hot tensor for your machine learning models (you have `tensorflow` or `keras` installed) then you can use `one_hot` function from https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/one_hot or https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/one_hot

It's what I'm using and is working well for high dimensional data.

Here's example usage:

```py
>>> import tensorflow as tf

>>> tf.one_hot([[0,2],[1,3]], 4).numpy()
array([[[1., 0., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 1., 0.]],

       [[0., 1., 0., 0.],
        [0., 0., 0., 1.]]], dtype=float32)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Edit:* I just realized that my answer is covered already in the accepted answer. Unfortunately, as an unregistered user, I cannot delete it any more.

As an addendum to the accepted answer: If you have a very small number of classes to encode and if you can accept `np.bool` arrays as output, I found the following to be even slightly faster:

```
def onehot_initialization_v3(a):
    ncols = a.max() + 1
    labels_one_hot = (a.ravel()[np.newaxis] == np.arange(ncols)[:, np.newaxis]).T
    labels_one_hot.shape = a.shape + (ncols,)
    return labels_one_hot
```

Timings (for 10 classes):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,10,(100,100))
assert np.all(onehot_initialization_v2(a) == onehot_initialization_v3(a))
%timeit onehot_initialization_v2(a)
%timeit onehot_initialization_v3(a)

# 102 µs ± 1.66 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 79.3 µs ± 815 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
```

This changes, however, if the number of classes increases (now 100 classes):

```
a = np.random.randint(0,100,(100,100))
assert np.all(onehot_initialization_v2(a) == one_hot_initialization_v3(a))
%timeit onehot_initialization_v2(a)
%timeit onehot_initialization_v3(a)

# 132 µs ± 1.4 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
# 639 µs ± 3.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

So, depending on your problem, either might be the faster version.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simplest and most elegant solution using **np.eye** (identity matrix) and numpy powerful indexing :

```
labels_3d = np.eye(N_CLASSES)[labels_2d]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I want to contribute by a simple advanced indexing solution, which is given in some other answers, in a more accessible way, without utilizing "helper functions" and all that.

We have a 2-dimensional array **a** which is categorical. For simplicity let us take it to be binary, for example:

```
a = (np.random.rand(40) > 0.5).astype(int).reshape(5, 8)

print(a)
>>>    array([
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]])
```

We create the one hot encoded array by initializing it to zero:

```
onehot = np.zeros((5, 8, 2))
```

We do [advanced indexing](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#assigning-values-to-indexed-arrays) to extract the places we want to put 1 on the one-hot encoded array. We let

```
x = np.arange(5).reshape(5, 1)
y = np.arange(8).reshape(1, 8)
```

The reshaping is to make them broadcastable.

```
onehot[x, y, a] = 1.
```

will first broadcast x, y, and a which are broadcastable to shape (5, 8). Then it will extract an array of that shape, whose values are taken from the onehot array. It will make that array an array of ones, and it will pull back those changes to the onehot array.

With the last command, we tell numpy to make assignments in specific coordinates given by the arrays x, y, a. They corresponds to the 3 dimensions of onehot. The number of assignments done is determined by the number of elements in the broadcasted array of x, y, a. In this case it is of shape (5, 8), so we make 40 assignments. Each assignment has its own 2 dimensional coordinate, let us donate them with i and j. The assignment (i, j) has target index in onehot given by `(x[i, j], y[i, j], a[i, j])`, extra coordinates are interpreted with the broadcasted version. x[i, j] is just i and y[i, j] is j. So we are actually targeting onehot[i, j, a[i, j]]. We use a as the last coordinate, which is the onehot target of the i,j'th entry. In other words, the (i, j)^th command is to flip the required class in onehot array corresponding to (i, j)^th entry.