# Index n dimensional array with (n-1) d array

Tags: python, numpy

What is the most elegant way to access an n dimensional array with an (n-1) dimensional array along a given dimension as in the dummy example

```
a = np.random.random_sample((3,4,4))
b = np.random.random_sample((3,4,4))
idx = np.argmax(a, axis=0)
```

How can I access now with `idx a` to get the maxima in `a` as if I had used `a.max(axis=0)`? or how to retrieve the values specified by `idx` in `b`?

I thought about using `np.meshgrid` but I think it is an overkill. Note that the dimension `axis` can be any usefull axis (0,1,2) and is not known in advance. Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Make use of [`advanced-indexing`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing) -

```
m,n = a.shape[1:]
I,J = np.ogrid[:m,:n]
a_max_values = a[idx, I, J]
b_max_values = b[idx, I, J]
```

---

For the general case:

```
def argmax_to_max(arr, argmax, axis):
    """argmax_to_max(arr, arr.argmax(axis), axis) == arr.max(axis)"""
    new_shape = list(arr.shape)
    del new_shape[axis]

    grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, new_shape))]
    grid.insert(axis, argmax)

    return arr[tuple(grid)]
```

Quite a bit more awkward than such a natural operation should be, unfortunately.

For indexing a `n dim` array with a `(n-1) dim` array, we could simplify it a bit to give us the grid of indices for all axes, like so -

```
def all_idx(idx, axis):
    grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, idx.shape))]
    grid.insert(axis, idx)
    return tuple(grid)
```

Hence, use it to index into input arrays -

```
axis = 0
a_max_values = a[all_idx(idx, axis=axis)]
b_max_values = b[all_idx(idx, axis=axis)]
```

Comment: As I said I don't know in advance that `axis` is 0 it can be any other value. This would change the order of `[idx, I, J]` so this will not work. And is basically the idea I mentioned with meshgrid...

Comment: @user2357112 Thanks for the help! Works nicely as a generic solution.

Comment: `all_idx` is really elegant. Love your posts, @Divakar!

Comment: Why did you choose to make `all_idx` return a tuple? Is there a case where returning `grid` (as a list) would not suffice?

Comment: @unutbu Well `all_idx` is mostly based on the edits by user2357112 and that had `tuple`. At my end with Python2.x, it worked fine without the tuple, but I wasn't sure if this would have worked on Python3.x. Need to test that out. Any insights?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing), advanced indexing is triggered by any non-tuple sequence object, so I think letting `grid` be a list should work.

Comment: @unutbu Ah I see now! So, if the input `a` is a 1D array, then with tuple, we would get a scalar, which replicates `.max()` behavior. But without tuple we would get an array with one elem. So, maybe that's one reason to keep it as a tuple I think.

Comment: `all_idx` is nice. I didn't realize using the argmax output's shape instead of the original array's shape would simplify things. As for the tuple instead of a list, the advanced indexing semantics are cleaner with a tuple. The list happens to behave the same in this case due to a (not-quite-correctly-documented) bit of backward compatibility handling that converts a list to a tuple under certain conditions. It can be surprising when a list is treated like a tuple and when a list is treated like an array in NumPy indexing, so I prefer to create the tuple explicitly.

Comment: For reference, the backward compatibility handling I'm referring to is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/7ccf0e08917d27bc0eba34013c1822b00a66ca6d/numpy/core/src/multiarray/mapping.c#L200). The case where `idx` is a scalar is something I didn't even think about, where the backward compatibility handling isn't triggered and the wrong result would occur if we kept a list instead of a tuple. As this demonstrates, the tuple's behavior is more consistent and easier to predict.

Comment: Subtle thing I realized later when trying to adapt this technique to a different problem: `np.ogrid[:5]` is `array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])`, but `np.ogrid[:5,]`, with the tuple, is `[array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])]`. Fortunately, things work out the way we need them to for this answer.

Comment: `take_along_axis` has been added to make this easier.  And a `put`

Comment: 1) This is amazing.  2) This doesn't work if axis is negative

Comment: @hpaulj Thanks. `np.squeeze(np.take_along_axis(a, np.expand_dims(idx, axis=axis), axis), axis=axis)` gives the same result as `a[all_idx(idx, axis)]`

Answer (score -1):

I suggest the following:

```
a = np.array([[1, 3], [2, -2], [1, -1]])
a
>array([[ 1,  3],
       [ 2, -2],
       [ 1, -1]])

idx = a.argmax(axis=1)
idx
> array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
    
np.take_along_axis(a, idx[:, None], axis=1).squeeze()
>array([3, 2, 1])

a.max(axis=1)
>array([3, 2, 1])
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

using indexing in numpy https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/reference/arrays.indexing.html#advanced-indexing

```
a = np.array([[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]])
a
> a: array([[1, 2], 
           [3, 4],
           [5, 6]])
```

```
idx = a.argmax(axis=1)
idx
> array([1, 0, 0], dtype=int64)
```

since you want all rows but only columns with idx indexes you can use [0, 1, 2] or np.arange(a.shape[0]) for the row indexes

```
rows = np.arange(a.shape[0])
a[rows, idx]
>array([3, 2, 1])
```

which is the same as a.max(axis=1)

```
a.max(axis=1)
>array([3, 2, 1])
```

if you have 3 dimensions you add the indexes of the 3rd dimension as well:

```
index2 = np.arange(a.shape[2]) 
a[rows, idx, index2]
```

Comment: I added a third dimension.