# Indexing a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Consider the following scenario.

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.randint(0,21,size=(10,64,64))
y = np.random.rand(10,21,64,64)

z = np.empty((10,64,64))

for i in range(10):
    for j in range(64):
        for k in range(64):
            z[i][j][k] = y[i][x[i][j][k]][j][k]
```

What is the recommended (in terms of speed) way to implement this behavior using numpy indexing?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103044/index-n-dimensional-array-with-n-1-d-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is exactly the aim of [`np.choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html#numpy.choose), You just need to rearange  y axis first.

```
In [6]: z2=np.choose(x,np.rollaxis(y,1))

In [7]: np.allclose(z,z2)
Out[7]: True
```

It's 15x faster than the loop method.