# Avoiding memory error when using numpy's argsort

Tags: python, numpy

the following sourcecode produces a memoryerror on my machine:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.random.random([100,100,100])
y = np.random.random([100,100,100])
c_sort = np.argsort(x, axis = 2)
f = y[c_sort]
```

Do you have a nice and easy idea how to avoid the memory error?

The other way to do this is

```
x = np.random.random([100,100,100])
y = np.random.random([100,100,100])
f = np.zeros([100,100,100])
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        f[i,j,:] = y[i,j, np.argsort(x[i,j,:])]
```

But I wonder why the solutions above does not lead to the same result?

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Comment: Hi Ignacio, I'm trying to sort y accoding to the order of (the second axis) of x.

Comment: Are you sure you want `y[c_sort]` for that? Do it on a small example and see if that's what you really need. You might be looking to do advanced-indexing, as shown here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46103044/index-n-dimensional-array-with-n-1-d-array

Comment: Dear Divakar, I am totally sure I need y[c_sort]. I want the *whole* ndarray to be sorted according to the second axis.

Comment: Well then you would have an output of shape `(100, 100, 100, 100, 100)`. Can your system RAM handle that?

Comment: @Divakar: Okay, maybe I am mistaken by the syntax...

Comment: So, which one's the correct version? The `y[c_sort]` one would produce different result I think. If the loopy one is the correct one, then the earlier linked post should solve your case, if you were looking to optimize.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162827/discussion-between-varantir-and-divakar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion in the comments, it seems the loopy version is the correct one. So, to optimize it, we can use `advanced-indexing`. Thus, given the argsort indices as `idx = np.argsort(x,axis=2)`, we can have `f` like so -

```
m,n = y.shape[:2]
f = y[np.arange(m)[:,None,None], np.arange(n)[:,None], idx]
```

Generic helper function for `advanced-indexing` [`take_along_axis`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47048882/) could be useful.