# filter numpy array into separate arrays based on value, for contour plotting

Tags: python, sorting, numpy, plot

I have numpy data which I am trying to turn into contour plot data. I realize this can be done through matplotlib, but I am trying to do this with just numpy if possible.

So, say I have an array of numbers 1-10, and and I want to divide the array according to contour "levels". I want to turn the input array into an array of boolean arrays, each of those being the size of the input, with a 1/True for any data point in that contour level and 0/False everywhere else.

For example, suppose the input is:

```
[1.2,2.3,3.4,2.5]
```

And the levels are [1,2,3,4],

then the return should be:

```
[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
```

So here is the start of an example I whipped up:
    import numpy as np

```
a = np.random.rand(3,3)*10
print(a)
b = np.zeros(54).reshape((6,3,3))

levs = np.arange(6)

#This is as far as I've gotten:
bins = np.digitize(a, levs)
print(bins)
```

I can use np.digitize to find out which level each value in a should belong to, but that's as far as I get. I'm fairly new to numpy and this really has me scratching me head. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could gather the indices off `np.digitize` output, which would represent the indices along the first `n-1` axes, where `n` is the no. of dims in output to be set in the output as `True` values. So, we could use indexing after setting up the output array or we could use a outer range comparison to achieve the same upon leverage `broadcasting`.

Hence, with `broadcasting` one that covers generic n-dim arrays -

```
idx = np.digitize(a, levs)-1
out = idx==(np.arange(idx.max()+1)).reshape([-1,]+[1]*idx.ndim)
```

With `indexing-based` one re-using `idx` from previous method, it would be -

```
# https://stackoverflow.com/a/46103129/ @Divakar
def all_idx(idx, axis):
    grid = np.ogrid[tuple(map(slice, idx.shape))]
    grid.insert(axis, idx)
    return tuple(grid)

out = np.zeros((idx.max()+1,) + idx.shape,dtype=int) #dtype=bool for bool array
out[all_idx(idx,axis=0)] = 1
```

Sample run -

```
In [77]: a = np.array([1.2,2.3,3.4,2.5])

In [78]: levs = np.array([1,2,3,4])

In [79]: idx = np.digitize(a, levs)-1
    ...: out = idx==(np.arange(idx.max()+1)).reshape([-1,]+[1]*idx.ndim)

In [80]: out.astype(int)
Out[80]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

Comment: This does what I need, but could you elaborate a bit on the line "out = ..."?