# Convert a 2D numpy array into a hot-encoded 3D numpy array, with same values in the same plane

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a Numpy array:

```py
[
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 4],
  [2, 0, 0],
]
```

How can I turn this into a "hot encoded" 3D array? something like this:

```py
[
  # Group of 0's
  [[1, 0, 1],
   [1, 0, 0],
   [0, 1, 1]],
  # Group of 1's
  [[0, 1, 0],
   [0, 1, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]],
  # Group of 2's
  [[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [1, 0, 0]],
  # Group of 3's
  # the group is still here, even though there are no threes
  [[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 0]],
  # Group of 4's
  [[0, 0, 0],
   [0, 0, 1],
   [0, 0, 0]]
]
```

That is, how can I take each occurrence of a number in the array and "group" them into their own plane in a 3D matrix? As shown in the example, even the "gap" in numbers (i.e. the `3`) should still appear. In my case, I know the range of the data beforehand (range `(0, 6]`), so that should make it easier.

BTW, I need this because I have a chessboard represented by numbers, but need it in this form to pass into a 2d convolutional neural network (different "channels" for different pieces).

I've seen [Convert a 2d matrix to a 3d one hot matrix numpy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960320/convert-a-2d-matrix-to-a-3d-one-hot-matrix-numpy), but that has a one-hot encoding for every value, which isn't what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create the desired array (`arr.max()+1` here) and then reshape it to compare to the original array:

Setup:

```
arr = np.array([
  [0, 1, 0],
  [0, 1, 4],
  [2, 0, 0],
])
```

---

```
u = np.arange(arr.max()+1)
(u[:,np.newaxis,np.newaxis]==arr).astype(int)
```

---

```
array([[[1, 0, 1],
        [1, 0, 0],
        [0, 1, 1]],

       [[0, 1, 0],
        [0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [1, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]],

       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0]]])
```