# What is the CNTK way to convert a vector that contains labels as indices to a one hot-representation?

Tags: cntk

In CNTK I need a way to convert a vector that contains labels as indices (just a regular vector, not a sparse representation) to a one hot-representation.

Here is an example for 5 classes:

Input

```
[2, 0, 1, 1]
```

Desired output:

```
[[0,0,1,0,0],
[1,0,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0],
[0,1,0,0,0]]
```

Is there a way without going through Python/numpy?

Answer (score 2):

The ‘Value.one_hot’ method does this (converts to a sparseCSC matrix representation internally).

https://www.cntk.ai/pythondocs/cntk.html?highlight=one_hot#cntk.core.Value.one_hot

Comment: link isn't coming up.

Answer (score 0):

If you're going to use these labels as tags for output layer then probably you'll have to use a numpy array. You should look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831596/4535284).