# How does this one-hot vector conversion work?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, vector

When I was working on my machine learning project, I was looking for a line of code to turn my labels into one-hot vectors. I came across this nifty line of code from u/benanne on Reddit.

```
np.eye(n_labels)[target_vector]
```

For example, for a `target_vector = np.array([1, 4, 2, 1, 0, 1, 3, 2])`, it returns the one-hot coded values:

```
np.eye(5)[target_vector]
Out: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       ..., 
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.]])
```

While it definitely does work, I'm not sure how or why it works.

Comment: I've never seen a method this elegant for generating OHVs.

Comment: It's the second answer on the [top voted SO question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/numpy-1-hot-array).  Should probably be the accepted answer since it handles n-d 1HA's so well

Answer (score 9):

It's rather simple. `np.eye(n_labels)` creates an identity matrix of size `n_labels` then you use your `target_vector` to select rows, corresponding to the value of the current target, from that matrix. Since each row in an identity matrix contains exactly one `1` element and the rest `0`, each row will be a valid 'one hot coding'.

Comment: This is indexing a NumPy array using another array as described here: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays.
The first array is the Identity matrix of size _n_labels_. The second array selects the one-hot row corresponding to each target.

Answer (score 0):

`ndarray[[0]]` is to select the first line in the ndarray

```
t = np.arange(9).reshape(3,3)
print t
print t[[1]]
```

Output is

```
[[0 1 2]
 [3 4 5]
 [6 7 8]]
[[3 4 5]]
```