# How to create multiple column list of booleans from given list of integers in phython?

Tags: python, numpy

I am new to Python. I want to do following.

Input: A list of integers of size *n*. Each integer is in a range of 0 to 3.

Output: A multi-column (4 column in this case as integer range in 0-3 = 4) numpy list of size *n*. Each row of the new list will have the column corresponding to the integer value of Input list as True and rest of the columns as False.

E.g. Input list : [0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2], size = 6, Each integer is in range of 0-3

Output list :

```
Row 0: True  False  False  False
Row 1: False False  False  True
Row 2: False False  True   False
Row 3: False True   False  False
Row 4: False True   False  False
Row 5: False False  True   False
```

Now, I can start with 4 columns. Traverse through the input list and create this as follows,

```
output_columns[].
for i in Input list:
    output_column[i] = True
Create an output numpy list with output columns
```

Is this the best way to do this in Python? Especially for creating numpy list as an output.

If yes, How do I merge output_columns[] at the end to create numpy multidimensional list with each dimension as a column of output_columns.

If not, what would be the best (most time efficient way) to do this in Python?

Thank you,

Comment: Similar question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/numpy-1-hot-array

Answer (score 3):

> Is this the best way to do this in Python?

No, a more Pythonic and probably the best way is to use a simple broadcasting comparison as following:

```
In [196]: a = np.array([0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2])

In [197]: r = list(range(0, 4))

In [198]: a[:,None] == r
Out[198]: 
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]])
```

Comment: @Asterisk That's the essence of Vectorization.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating so called one-hot vector (each row in matrix is a one-hot vector meaning that only one value is True).

```
mylist = [0, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2]
one_hot = np.zeros((len(mylist), 4), dtype=np.bool)
for i, v in enumerate(mylist):
    one_hot[i, v] = True
```

**Output**

```
array([[ True, False, False, False],
       [False, False, False,  True],
       [False, False,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False,  True, False, False],
       [False, False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```