# Replace items in list with another items (small lists) depending on several conditions

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, foreach, linspace

I have a list of numbers and I want to replace each number with a list binary pattern depending on several conditions. I have a working code for doing so, but I am wondering if there is a faster more efficient one because if I wanted to add more conditions.

Thanks

```
import numpy as np
n = []
z = np.linspace(0,5,8)
t = [3.8856, 4.1820, 2.3040, 1.0197, 0.4295, 1.5178, 0.3853, 4.2848, 4.30911, 3.2299, 1.8528, 0.6553, 3.3305, 4.1504, 1.8787]
for i in t:
    if i>=z[0] and i<z[1]:
        n.extend([0,0,0,0,0])
    elif i>=z[1] and i<z[2]:
        n.extend([0,0,0,0,1])
    elif i>=z[2] and i<z[3]:
        n.extend([0,0,0,1,0])
    elif i>=z[3] and i<z[4]:
        n.extend([0,0,0,1,1])
    elif i>=z[4] and i<z[5]:
        n.extend([0,0,1,0,0])
    elif i>=z[5] and i<z[6]:
        n.extend([0,0,1,0,1])
    elif i>=z[6] and i<z[7]:
        n.extend([0,0,1,1,0])
new_n = np.asarray(n).reshape(len(t),5) # new_n is the final pattern I want.
```

Comment: Have you seen [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)?

Comment: @pylang Yes, I can see using it makes it faster as I don't have to loop there `t` I can change several indices at once if they match the condition, but what about listing the conditions themselves?

Comment: The condition statements are probably negligible compared to the O(n) loop and method calls.

Comment: n.extend([0,0,1,0,1])
    NameError: name 'n' is not defined

Comment: @AlexanderLopatin Corrected. Sorry!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an answer per se, but it probably will be faster due to using numpy rather than python's for loop.

First, you want to perform some [binning](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.digitize.html):

```
>> bins = np.digitize(t, z) - 1 # minus 1 just to align our shapes
array([5, 5, 3, 1, 0, 2, 0, 5, 6, 4, 2, 0, 4, 5, 2])
```

This tells you in what bin each of your values goes. Next, define your patterns, in order:

```
>> patterns = np.array([
    [0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,1],
    [0,0,0,1,0],
    [0,0,0,1,1],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,1],
    [0,0,1,1,0],
])
```

Now for some numpy magic, instead of appending/extending, create an array full of zeros (this should be almost always faster). This array will have shape `(len(t), len(z)-1)`. Using [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831596/6655150), we will also do one-hot encoding:

```
>> inds = np.zeros((len(t), len(z)-1))
>> inds[np.arange(len(t)), bins] = 1
>> inds
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       .....,
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

Finally, all we need to is a matrix multiplication

```
>> inds @ patterns
array([[0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 1.],
       ....
       [0., 0., 1., 0., 1.],
       [0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

I did not perform a quality timing test, but from my minor experimentation here are my results:

Your loop: 17.7 µs ± 160 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
My implementation: 8.49 µs ± 125 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Which may or may not scale well to larger datasets. Hope this helps :)

---

Edit: Following [Alexander Lopatin's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55113228/6655150) answer I was interested to see that my method was significantly slower. Upon further investigation one of the conclusions I arrived at was that `numpy`'s functions have some significant overhead which is not a cheap price to pay for few values of `t`. For larger lists, the numpy overhead is insignificant, but the performance gain is not:

[image]

```
timings = {
    10: [7.79, 24.1, 21.7],
    16: [10.7, 29.9, 22.9],
    24: [14.6, 40.5, 23.4],
    33: [19.1, 48.6, 23.4],
    38: [21.9, 55.9, 23.9],
    47: [26.7, 66.2, 24.1],
    61: [33, 79.5, 24.7],
    75: [40.8, 92.6, 25.8],
    89: [47.6, 108, 26.2],
    118: [60.1, 136, 27.4],
    236: [118, 264, 33.1],
    472: [236, 495, 40.9],
    1000: [657, 922, 52],
    10000: [6530, 9090, 329]
}
```

Zoom:

[image]

Comment: **Binning**! Now I know that Mr. Bin has a verb :-)

Comment: I was trying to incorporate your answer in my code:

    inds = np.zeros((len(t), len(z) - 1), **dtype=int**
    inds = **inds** @ patterns

The results and times are also not the same:

    Time    CPU for 100000 loops
    1.7117  1.7052 Alexander
    4.6044  4.5888 Kotlas

Comment: I wouldn't trust my timings over yours, I just used the `%%timeit` in jupyter. Still, the difference amazes me, but anyhow thanks for including those in your answer! Edit: I also noticed that I had a few mistakes in the `patterns` variable, fixing these too.

Comment: I forgot to mention that using your code the timings are roughly the same as the ones you reported. I was interested though as why the difference in performance, and decided to do some more testing. It seems the problem does not lie with the timing method. I tried the following: I increased the size of `t` from 15 to 100 and the timings are: me 2.54, you 4.92, original 11.53, but I also noticed another thing: wrapping it in a function nearly doubles the time it takes (from 12.2μs to 26.5μs). I tried using `cProfile` and `dis.dis` but couldn't find the source of that. Any ideas?

Comment: If you don't wrap in a function you may be reusing something that was created in the global scope. The green time is just flat? Check your code and provide it. so I can test it too :-)

Comment: It's not flat, it simply grows slower (I've also attached the timings in a dictionary). The code is exactly the same as yours with only one difference: instead of `t = [...]` I used `t = np.repeat([...], n_repeats)`. I ran it with multiple n_repeats and logged the results, but do check it out in case I missed something (again...).

Answer (score 1):

**My new version is three-time faster than the original:**

```
Time    CPU for 100000 loops
1.7444  1.7400 proposed by Alexander Lopatin
5.2813  5.2770 original by motaha
4.6203  4.6117 proposed by Kostas Mouratidis
```

I simplified the **elif**s to make the original code smaller (11 lines) and then added some 57 lines (66..123) for speed and correctness testing :-)  Tried also to use **z = np.linspace(0,5,8)** or precalculate z outside the for in loop 'if z[j] < y < z[j+1]:' instead of 'if x*j < y < x*(j+1):', but got big time penalty - don't know why. I also added the code proposed here by Kostas Mouratidis. It didn't produce the exact result, see the output at the end.

```
import numpy as np
import itertools
import time
import platform


def f1():  # answered by Alexander Lopatin #####################################
    n = []
    t = [3.8856, 4.1820, 2.3040, 1.0197,  0.4295,
         1.5178, 0.3853, 4.2848, 4.30911, 3.2299,
         1.8528, 0.6553, 3.3305, 4.1504,  1.8787]
    x = 5./7.
    p = list(itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=5))
    for y in t:
        j = int(y/x)
        if x*j < y < x*(j+1):
            n.append(p[j])
    return np.asarray(n).reshape(len(t), 5)


def f2():  # original post by motaha ###########################################
    n = []
    t = [3.8856, 4.1820, 2.3040, 1.0197, 0.4295,
         1.5178, 0.3853, 4.2848, 4.30911,3.2299,
         1.8528, 0.6553, 3.3305, 4.1504, 1.8787]
    z = np.linspace(0,5,8)
    for i in t:
        if i>=z[0] and i<z[1]:
            n.extend([0,0,0,0,0])
        elif i>=z[1] and i<z[2]:
            n.extend([0,0,0,0,1])
        elif i>=z[2] and i<z[3]:
            n.extend([0,0,0,1,0])
        elif i>=z[3] and i<z[4]:
            n.extend([0,0,0,1,1])
        elif i>=z[4] and i<z[5]:
            n.extend([0,0,1,0,0])
        elif i>=z[5] and i<z[6]:
            n.extend([0,0,1,0,1])
        elif i>=z[6] and i<z[7]:
            n.extend([0,0,1,1,0])
    return np.asarray(n).reshape(len(t),5)


def f3(): # answered by Kostas Mouratidis ######################################
    n = []
    t = [3.8856, 4.1820, 2.3040, 1.0197, 0.4295,
         1.5178, 0.3853, 4.2848, 4.30911,3.2299,
         1.8528, 0.6553, 3.3305, 4.1504, 1.8787]
    z = np.linspace(0,5,8)
    bins = np.digitize(t, z) - 1  # minus 1 just to align our shapes
    patterns = np.array([
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 1, 0, 1],
        [0, 0, 1, 1, 1],
    ])
    inds = np.zeros((len(t), len(z) - 1), dtype=int)
    inds[np.arange(len(t)), bins] = 1
    inds = inds @ patterns
    return inds

# Testing ... ##################################################################


def correct_cpu(cpu_time):
    pv1, pv2, _ = platform.python_version_tuple()
    pcv = platform.python_compiler()
    if pv1 == '3' and '5' <= pv2 <= '8' and pcv == 'Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)':
        cpu_time /= 2.0
    return cpu_time


def test(test_function, test_loops, test_name):
    t = time.perf_counter()
    c = time.process_time()
    test_result = []
    for j in range(0, test_loops):
        test_result = test_function()
    t = time.perf_counter() - t
    c = correct_cpu(time.process_time() - c)
    print('%.4f  %.4f %s' % (t, c, test_name))
    return test_result

print('Python version  :', platform.python_version())
print('       build    :', platform.python_build())
print('       compiler :', platform.python_compiler())
print()
loops = 100000
f2test = [(f1, 'proposed by Alexander Lopatin'),
          (f2, 'original by motaha'),
          (f3, 'proposed by Kostas Mouratidis')]
print('Time    CPU for', loops, 'loops')

results = []
for func, name in f2test:
    results.append(test(func, loops, name))

original = 1
_, name = f2test[original]
print('\nthe final pattern I want! ' + name)
print(results[original])
for order, result in enumerate(results):
    if order == original:
        continue
    _, name = f2test[order]
    error = False
    for i_row, row in enumerate(result):
        for j_column, value in enumerate(row):
            if value != results[original][i_row][j_column]:
                error = True
                print('\n*** Check for ERRORS in (%d,%d) %s '
                      % (i_row, j_column, name))
                break
        if error:
            break
    if error:
        print(result)
    else:
        print('The same ' + name)
```

Output:

```
Python version  : 3.8.0a2
       build    : ('v3.8.0a2:23f4589b4b', 'Feb 25 2019 10:59:08')
       compiler : Clang 6.0 (clang-600.0.57)

Time    CPU for 100000 loops
1.7444  1.7400 proposed by Alexander Lopatin
5.2813  5.2770 original by motaha
4.6203  4.6117 proposed by Kostas Mouratidis

the final pattern I want! original by motaha
[[0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
The same proposed by by Alexander Lopatin

*** Check for ERRORS in (4,4) proposed by Kostas Mouratidis 
[[0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 1 1 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 0 1 0]
 [0 0 0 0 1]
 [0 0 1 0 0]
 [0 0 1 0 1]
 [0 0 0 1 0]]
```

Comment: This gives me the exact same time as my implementation, but the use of itertools was nice to see. +1

Answer (score 0):

In Python there isn't really a way to condense unlike the Java switch case. If you really want to spend some time, there's this [tutorial](https://jaxenter.com/implement-switch-case-statement-python-138315.html) to build your own switch case in Python.

Otherwise the only real improvement that can be made is condensed comparisons like `z[0]<=i<z[1]`.