# One hot encoding a numpy array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I'm working on an image classification problem where I got the train labels as a 1-D numpy array, like `[1,2,3,2,2,2,4,4,3,1]`. I used

```
train_y = []
for label in train_label:
    if label == 0:
        train_y.append([1,0,0,0])
    elif label == 1:
        train_y.append([0,1,0,0])
    elif label == 2:
        train_y.append([0,0,1,0])
    elif label == 3:
        train_y.append([0,0,0,1])
```

Also I need the `len(one_hot_array) = set(train_labels)`,
but this is not a good method. Please recommend a good method to do so.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert array of indices to 1-hot encoded numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-1-hot-encoded-numpy-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's always a good habit to use numpy for arrays. `np.unique()` determins the labels you have in `train_labels`. `ix` is an array of indices. `np.nonzero()` gives the indices of `train_lables` where `train_labels == unique_tl[iy]`.

```
import numpy as np

train_labels = np.array([2,5,8,2,5,8])
unique_tl = np.unique(train_labels)

NL = len(train_labels)               # how many data , 6
nl = len(unique_tl)                  # how many labels, 3   
target = np.zeros((NL,nl),dtype=int)

for iy in range(nl):
    ix = np.nonzero(train_labels == unique_tl[iy]) 
    target[ix,iy] = 1
```

gives

```
target
array([[1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1],
       [1, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0],
       [0, 0, 1]])
```

I'll think about a possibility to eliminate the for-loop.

If [2,5,8] is meant as part of [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8], then you can use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-1-hot-encoded-numpy-array?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: This is the exact solution I wanted ..Thank you very much for your time :-)

Comment: Great :-). And since you are rather new here: If you find some useful answers here in StackOverflow then you can give an upvote (orange up-arrow on the left of the text field). If you have asked a question yourself and have got an answer, that solves your problem you might click "solved" (= check sign below the up/down arrows, which becomes green) too

Comment: Yep.. But for the upvote it says "Vote cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded but do not change the publicly displayed post score" :-(

Comment: it is as it is … :-)

Answer (score 0):

make a vector of zeros, and set only one value to 1

```
target = np.zeros(num_classes)
target[label] = 1
train_y.append(target)
```

Comment: What if the train_labels = [2,5,8,2,5,8], means they are not from 0 to 4. where i can just use the values of labels as indices