# One hot encoding a list of characters with unobserved levels

Tags: python, one-hot-encoding

I am tryng to create a one hot encoding (ohe) of a list of characters allowing for unobserved levels. Using answers from [Convert array of indices to 1-hot encoded numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-1-hot-encoded-numpy-array) and [Finding the index of an item given a list containing it in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/176918/finding-the-index-of-an-item-given-a-list-containing-it-in-python), the following does want I want:

```
# example data
# this is the full list including unobserved levels
av = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1))) 
# this is the vector to apply ohe
v = ['a', 'f', 'u'] 

# apply one hot encoding
ohe = np.zeros((len(v), len(av)))
for i in range(len(v)): ohe[i, av.index(v[i])] = 1
ohe
```

Is there a more standard/faster way to do this, noting that the second link above mentions the bottleneck of `.index()`.

(scale of my problem: full vector (av) has ~1000 levels, and the values to ohe (v) is of length 0.5M. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a lookup dictionary:

```
# example data
# this is the full list including unobserved levels
av = list(map(chr, range(ord('a'), ord('z')+1)))
lookup = { v : i for i, v in enumerate(av)}

# this is the vector to apply ohe
v = ['a', 'f', 'u']

# apply one hot encoding
ohe = np.zeros((len(v), len(av)))
for i in range(len(v)):
    ohe[i, lookup[v[i]]] = 1
```

The complexity of `.index` is `O(n)` vs looking in a dictionary that is `O(1)`. You can even save the for loop by doing:

```
indices = [lookup[vi] for vi in v]
ohe = np.zeros((len(v), len(av)))
ohe[np.arange(len(v)), indices] = 1
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)