# Elegant way to encode a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, encoding, one-hot-encoding

Currently I am trying to one hot encode a list of lists that contain single elements. What is a clean Pythonic way to go from representation 2 to representation 1? Additionally I would like to know a clean approach to go from representation 1 to representation 2.

Representation 1

```
[[1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 ...
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
(256, 6)
```

Representation 2

```
[[0.]
 [3.]
 [3.]
 ...
 [2.]
 [3.]
 [2.]]
(256, 1)
```

Answer (score 3):

Using pure basic conditionnal list comprehension, for representation 1 to 2:

```
r1 = [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]]
len_r1l = len(r1[0]) # length of each sublist, here 6

r2 = [[0], [3], [4]]

r1_r2 = [[i] for l in r1 for i in range(len_r1l) if l[i]==1]
>>> [[0], [3], [4]]
```

and for representation 2 to 1:

```
r2_r1 = [[1. if i==idx[0] else 0 for i in range(len_r1l)] for idx in r2]
>>> [[1.0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0, 0],
     [0, 0, 0, 0, 1.0, 0]]
```

Equivalently by using numpy, with [np.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html):

```
# convert to array
r1_np = np.asarray(r1)
r2_np = np.asarray(r2)

r1_r2 = np.nonzero(r1_np)[1]
>>> array([0, 3, 4])

r2_r1 = np.zeros_like(r1_np)
r2_r1[np.arange(r1_r2.shape[0]),r1_r2] = 1.
>>> array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
           [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]])
```

then if you really want to keep it to `list` use [np.ndarray.tolist](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.tolist.html) method:

```
r1_r2.tolist()
>>> [0, 3, 4]
r2_r1.tolist()
>>> [[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0],
     [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]]
```

Benchmarking these answers for intended input of size `256` clearly shows numpy's efficiency:

```
# representation 1 to 2
%timeit [[i] for l in r1 for i in range(len_r1l) if l[i]==1]
>>> 199 µs ± 431 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit np.nonzero(r1_np)[1]
>>> 13 µs ± 32.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

# representation 2 to 1
%timeit [[1. if i==idx[0] else 0 for i in range(len_r1l)] for idx in r2]
>>> 243 µs ± 820 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

%timeit r2_r1 = np.zeros_like(r1_np); r2_r1[np.arange(r1_r2.shape[0]),r1_r2] = 1.
>>> 9.42 µs ± 15.8 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

**Representation 1 --> 2:**

If you know that every list will have one and only one `1`, you can use [`list.index`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) in a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
list_of_lists = [  # Your initial list
    [1, 0, 0],
    [0, 1, 0],
    [0, 0, 1]
]

list_of_ones_indices = [[lst.index(1)] for lst in list_of_lists]
# [0, 1, 2]
```

---

**Representation 2 --> 1:**

[This numpy solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29831596/3801865) might be closer to what you're looking for. If you want a pure-Python solution, here you go:

```
index_list = [1, 2, 3]
LENGTH = 6
one_hot_list = []

# This can also be achieved with a list comprehension and range()
for index in index_list:
    one_hot = [0] * LENGTH
    one_hot[index[0]] = 1
    one_hot_list.append(one_hot)

print(one_hot_list)
# [
#     [0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0],
#     [0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
# ]
```

Comment: Note that in the first case your answer is a list and not a list of lists as in the question

Answer (score 0):

For converting from representation 2 to representation 1, you can use something like `keras.np_utils.to_categorical`:

```
>>> y = [0, 1, 2]
>>> np_utils.to_categorical(y)
array([[ 1., 0., 0.],
       [ 0., 1., 0.],
       [ 0., 0., 1.]])
```

Comment: Note that it concerns a list of lists: [[0], [1], [2]] instead of [0, 1, 2].

Answer (score 0):

IIUC,

```
np.argmax(a, axis=1)[:, None]
```

Using @Yacola setup:

```
r1 = [[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 1., 0., 0.],
      [0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 0.]]

a = np.array(r1)
np.argmax(a, axis=1)[:, None]
```

Output:

```
array([[0],
       [3],
       [4]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Using numpy,

```
rep_2 = np.where(condition)[1].reshape(rep1.shape[0], 1)
```

where `condition` could be stated in many ways, of which are:

- rep_1 == 1
- rep_1 != 0

Depending upon your requirement. Convert rep_2 to a list if you so wish.