# Matlab Function equivalence in Python

Tags: python, matlab

I was writing code in Matlab and had to return a matrix which gave a 0 or 1 to represent elements in the original matrix.

I wanted to know if there is a python equivalent of the above without running nested loops to achieve the same result.

```
c = [2; 1; 3]
temp = eye(3,3)
d = temp(c,:)
```

the d matrix needs to tell me what number was present in my original matrix.
i = 1, j = 2 if 1 tells me the first element of the original matrix was 2

Comment: I did put an answer, but on second thoughts, I don't think it generates the same output as you . Could you display `d` to show an example of the desired output? Is the idea to return an array of the size of `c` where the elements equal to `k` are replaced by `1` and the others by `0`?

Comment: what you are looking for is called `one-hot` encoding (or alternatively `one-of-K`). I'm sure there's hundreds of duplicates here.

Comment: One-hot encoding: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-1-hot-encoded-numpy-array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "direct" equivalent of that code is this (note the 0-indexing, compared to matlab's 1-indexing)

```
import numpy
c    = numpy.array( [1, 0, 2] )
temp = numpy.eye( 3 )
d    = temp[c, :]
```

Here is the link to the documentation on [how to index using 'index arrays' in the official numpy documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays)

However, in general what you are doing above is called "one hot" encoding (or "one-of-K", as per Bishop2006). There are specialised methods for one hot encoding in the various machine learning toolkits, which confer some advantages, so you may prefer to look those up instead.

Comment: Brilliant! I wrote the same code. Almost. In my case, however, I didn't replace the 3 in the c array. Completely forgot that Matlab indexing is different from Python's