# Why does my program keep on crashing after i write "epoch" even when I'm following a tutorial?

Tags: python, tensorflow

so I'm using python for some basic stuff, and I was following a tutorial on handwritten digits. But whenever I do:

> model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

it always crashes....

This is my piece of code that from the tutorial

```
import tensorflow as tf

mnist= tf.keras.datasets.mnist

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test)= mnist.load_data()

x_train= tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_train, axis=1)
x_test= tf.keras.utils.normalize(x_test, axis=1)

model= tf.keras.models.Sequential()
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Flatten())

model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation= tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation= tf.nn.relu))
model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation= tf.nn.softmax))

#always trying to minimize "loss"
model.compile(optimizer= 'adam', 
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)
```

and this is the error that I get:

```
Epoch 1/3
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-67c2d7c319b1> in <module>
     19               loss='categorical_crossentropy',
     20               metrics=['accuracy'])
---> 21 model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=3)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1181                 _r=1):
   1182               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1183               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1184               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1185                 context.async_wait()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    887 
    888       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 889         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    890 
    891       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    931       # This is the first call of __call__, so we have to initialize.
    932       initializers = []
--> 933       self._initialize(args, kwds, add_initializers_to=initializers)
    934     finally:
    935       # At this point we know that the initialization is complete (or less

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in _initialize(self, args, kwds, add_initializers_to)
    761     self._graph_deleter = FunctionDeleter(self._lifted_initializer_graph)
    762     self._concrete_stateful_fn = (
--> 763         self._stateful_fn._get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(  # pylint: disable=protected-access
    764             *args, **kwds))
    765 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _get_concrete_function_internal_garbage_collected(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3048       args, kwargs = None, None
   3049     with self._lock:
-> 3050       graph_function, _ = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3051     return graph_function
   3052 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3442 
   3443           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)
-> 3444           graph_function = self._create_graph_function(args, kwargs)
   3445           self._function_cache.primary[cache_key] = graph_function
   3446 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3277     arg_names = base_arg_names + missing_arg_names
   3278     graph_function = ConcreteFunction(
-> 3279         func_graph_module.func_graph_from_py_func(
   3280             self._name,
   3281             self._python_function,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes)
    997         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
    998 
--> 999       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1000 
   1001       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    670         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    671         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 672           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    673         return out
    674 

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    984           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    985             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 986               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    987             else:
    988               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:855 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:845 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:1285 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:2833 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\distribute\distribute_lib.py:3608 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:838 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py:796 train_step
        loss = self.compiled_loss(
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\compile_utils.py:204 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:155 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:259 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\losses.py:1643 categorical_crossentropy
        return backend.categorical_crossentropy(
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\backend.py:4862 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    C:\Users\binju\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (32, 1) and (32, 10) are incompatible
```

I've tried other tutorials too, but whenever I reach the model.fit part with epochs, it always seems to crash a lot?
Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: Hi, didn't have experience on tensor flow but I think the issue may be that your last layer has 10 neurons instead of 1.

Answer (score 0):

The mnist dataset has integer labels as y values, as you can read here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/datasets/mnist/load_data

You try to classify the data points into 10 classes with a one-hot classification, so you have a 10-dimensional neural network output, which does not correspond to your one-dimensional labels.

The solution is to convert your labels into one-hot encoded labels as well, you can find the solution for this problem here:

[Convert array of indices to 1-hot encoded numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-1-hot-encoded-numpy-array)