# Converting a 2D segmentation map to n dimensional numpy masks

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a segmentation map with 10 classes (A numpy array of size (m,n,1) which every element is a number from 1~10 specifying a class that the pixel belongs to). I want to convert it to an array of size (m,n,10) where each channel is mask for elements of that specific class. I can do it using a for loop like this:

```
for i in range(10):
    mask[:,:,i] = (seg_map==i)[:,:,0]
```

but I need a faster way to do this. The for loop takes too much time. Is there any built in function that can outperform the for loop.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Basically you want to one-hot encode the last array, right?

Comment: @DaniMesejo yeah exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach:

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

# toy data
data = np.random.randint(0, 10, 20).reshape((5, 4, 1))

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323404/4001592
n_values = 10
values = data.flatten()
encoded = np.eye(n_values)[data.ravel()].reshape((5, 4, 10))

match = np.allclose(data.reshape(5, 4), encoded.argmax(-1))
print(match)
```

One way to verify that the output is correct is to verify that the  one-hot encoded value matches back with the index, as below:

```
match = np.allclose(data.reshape(5, 4), encoded.argmax(-1))
print(match)
```

**Output**

```
True
```

Comment: Yeah that worked like charm :D Thanks :). the only thing I changed was n_value to 9 and every thing was fine. Thanks :)