# Python/Numpy get average of array based on index

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have two numpy arrays, the first one is the `values` and the second one is the `indexes`. What I want to do is to get the average of the `values` array based on the `indexes` array.

For example:

```
values = [1,2,3,4,5]
indexes = [0,0,1,1,2]
get_indexed_avg(values, indexes)
# should give me 
#   [1.5,    3.5,    5]
```

Here, the values in the `indexes` array represent the indexes in the final array. Hence:

1. First two items in the `values` array are being averaged to form the zero index in the final array.
2. The 3rd and the 4th item in the `values` array are being averaged to form the first index in the final array.
3. Finally the last item is being used to for the 2nd index in the final array.

I do have a python solution to this. But that is just horrible and very slow. Is there a better solution to this? maybe using numpy? or other such libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wanted to avoid pandas so I spent quite some time figuring it out.
The way to do this is by using what's called a [one-hot encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One-hot).

Creating a one-hot encoding of the indexes will give us a 2-d array with 1s at places where we want them. For example:

```
indexes = np.array([0,0,1,1,2])
# one_hot = array(
#    [[1., 0., 0.],
#    [1., 0., 0.],
#    [0., 1., 0.],
#    [0., 1., 0.],
#    [0., 0., 1.]]
# )
```

We just need to get a one-hot for the index array and mat-multiply it with the values to get what we want. Uses answer from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37323404/4272651) post

```
values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
indexes = np.array([0,0,1,1,2])

one_hot = np.eye(np.max(indexes) + 1)[indexes]

counts = np.sum(one_hot, axis=0)
average = np.sum((one_hot.T * values), axis=1) / counts

print(average) # [1.5 3.5 5.]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd
pd.Series(values).groupby(indexes).mean()
# OR
# pd.Series(values).groupby(indexes).mean().to_list()
# 0    1.5
# 1    3.5
# 2    5.0
# dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 1):

**The simplest and easy solution:**

```
values = np.array([1,2,3,4,5])
indexes = np.array([0,0,1,1,2])
index_set = set(indexes) # index_set = {0, 1, 2}

# Now get values based on the index that we saved in index_set 
# and then take an average
avg = [np.mean(values[indexes==k]) for k in index_set]

print(avg) # [1.5, 3.5, 5.0]
```