# How do I input 3-dimensional array sequence?

Tags: python, pytorch, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I am a Korean student studying natural language processing.

When I put a sentence in LSTM, I want to put it in a 3-dimensional array.
I'm going to change sentence `나는 집에서 친구와 밥을 먹었다.` like `[['나', '는'],['집','에서'],['친구','와'],['밥','을'],['먹','었','다','.']]`

and I will change words to vector (embedding). like:

```
[[ [1,0,0,0, ... ], [0,1,0,0, ... ] ], [ [0,0,1,0, ... ], [0,0,0,1, ...] ], [...], ...]
```

So, here's a 3-dimensional array in one sequence.

How do I input 3-dimensional array to one LSTM?????
[image: description]

Or, Is this possible???
Stupid question, I'm sorry.

I don't know how to change it.

```
class Tagger(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,
                 embedding_dim=43,
                 n_layers=4,
                 dropout=0.2,
                 output_dim=11,
                 bidirectional=False):
        super(WordTagger, self).__init__()

        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(embedding_dim, embedding_dim,
                            num_layers=n_layers, bidirectional=bidirectional)
        self.hidden_dim = (embedding_dim * 2) if bidirectional else embedding_dim
        self.linear = nn.Linear(self.hidden_dim, output_dim)
        self.dropout = nn.Dropout(dropout)

    def forward(self, embedded):
        lstmed, _ = self.lstm(embedded)
        outputs = self.linear(self.dropout(lstmed))
        scores = F.log_softmax(outputs, dim=1)

        return scores
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all use English. It could be better to get answer.

And, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29831489/convert-array-of-indices-to-one-hot-encoded-array-in-numpy) it could be helpful.

One hot encoding is popular for struct unordered matrix. search 'one hot encoding' in Korean with google. It could be find.